# Can I number child elements consecutively, even across parent elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks basically like this:

```
<course>
 <class>
  <person>
    <name>bob</name>
    <age>19</age>
  </person>
  <person>
     <name>john</name>
     <age>18</age>
  <person>
 </class>
 <class>
  <person>
    <name>jane</name>
    <age>19</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>greg</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </person>
 </class>
</course>
```

I also have all their grades, and because of the way my original data is set up, the easiest way for me to add all their grades is actually to add them via XSLT. So, I have XSLT that looks like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="course/class/person[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            <grade>A</grade>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="course/class/person[2]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            <grade>B</grade>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

This code works great to add all of the grades for `class[1]`, but I would like to use it to add `class[2]` (and 3 and 4 and so on) while keeping the `person` numbering consecutive, even across `class` elements. So, while Jane is actually `class[2]/person[1]`, I just want her to be `person[3]`. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean - perhaps add the expected result to clarify. Sounds like you want to use `xsl:number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 (and perhaps 2, would need to check in the spec) I think you can express e.g. `<xsl:template match="(//person)[3]">` to match the third `person` in the document or e.g. `<xsl:template match="(class/person)[3]">` to match the third `person` in the document that is a child of a `class`. It should also be possible in XSLT 3 to set up an accumulator counting `person`s.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want

```
<xsl:template match="course/class/person">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        <grade>
          <xsl:number level="any" from="course" format="A"/>
        </grade>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93YNgWu